# Outlook Ribbon Implementation for IRibbonUI

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook, outlook-addin, ribbon

I am confused about the implementation of the `IRibbonUI` interface that is exposed in the Outlook Object Model.

When the XML file for the either the Explorer or Inspector ribbon are written, we have to define which method will be responsible for loading the XML into Outlook.

Note: that this code was not originally written by me but I've been tasked to fix the solution..or at the least find a *reason why this thing doesn't work as expected*.

Anyways, the methods to set the ribbons are defined in the following methods: `Ribbon_OnLoad` and `ERibbon_OnLoad`

```
    Public Sub Ribbon_OnLoad(ByVal Ribbon As Office.IRibbonUI)
        m_Ribbon = Ribbon
    End Sub

    Public Sub ERibbon_OnLoad(ByVal Ribbon As Office.IRibbonUI)
        m_ERibbon = Ribbon
    End Sub
```

Now what I am confused is why the method for the Inspector never fires? When I step through the code and even when I open an inspector object, my global variable `m_Ribbon` is sometimes `Nothing` and vice versa for the `m_ERibbon` variable.

There have been times where `m_ERibbon` has been nothing and there has been times `m_Ribbon` has been nothing..I'm starting to think I may have deeply misunderstood how the Ribbon for Office works.

Now it becomes more intricate when I have to invoke the callbacks via the `Invalidate` method. I have an explorer wrapper and a inspector wrapper which invoke either `m_ERibbon.Invalidate()` or `m_Ribbon.Invalidate()` depending if the user is using the Explorer or Inspector.

What I do not understand is this:

1. Why doesn't `Ribbon_OnLoad` fire ALL the time, and why doesn't `ERibbon_OnLoad` fire all the time, despite the fact I've explictly set the `onLoad` method to fire these methods?
2. Why are there instances where `m_ERibbon` or `m_Ribbon` are `Nothing`?

From what I can tell is despite the `Invalidate()` method being invoked from the Explorer or the Inspector...the call to `Invalidate()` invokes ALL of the callbacks despite some callbacks being placed in the inspector and vice versa.

Have I understood this incorrectly?

**EDIT** I'm adding code for the `GetCustomUI` because this is where the markup is defined. Despite the respective XML markups being available for both the Explorer and the Inspector; the method `Ribbon_OnLoad` (for the Inspector) doesn't fire.

```
Function GetCustomUI(ByVal RibbonID As String) As String Implements Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility.GetCustomUI
    Select Case RibbonID
        Case "Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read"
            Return basRibbon.QFGetRibbonMailRead()
        Case "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer"
            Return basRibbon.GetRibbonExplorerFolder()
        Case Else
            Return String.Empty
    End Select
End Function
```

And a snippet of the XML markup is the following (note that this is for the Inspector):

```
sRibbonXML = "<customUI xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"" onLoad=""Ribbon_OnLoad"" >" & _
```

Snippet of the XML markup for the Explorer:

```
sRibbonXML = "<customUI xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"" onLoad=""ERibbon_OnLoad"" " & _
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office applications call the [GetCustomUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonextensibility.getcustomui.aspx) method to obtain an XML string that defines the user interface of your custom Ribbon.

```
public class Connect : Object, Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2, IRibbonExtensibility 
... 

public string GetCustomUI(string RibbonID) 
{ 

   StreamReader customUIReader = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\RibbonXSampleCS\\customUI.xml"); 

   string customUIData = customUIReader.ReadToEnd(); 

   return customUIData; 
 }
```

Note, sometimes you need to return the XML markup for different `ribbonID` values passed as an argument. In that case you will get the `onLoad` callback invoked (for inspectors too).

```
    public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
    {
        string ribbonXML = String.Empty;

        if (ribbonID == "Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose")
        {
            ribbonXML = GetResourceText("Trin_RibbonOutlookBasic.Ribbon1.xml");
        }

        return ribbonXML;
    }
```

See [Customizing a Ribbon for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398246.aspx) for more information.

You can read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Please remember that by default, if an VSTO add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom Ribbon does not appear, or why a Ribbon appears but no controls appear. See [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Eugene, thank you for your reply. Please see my edited answer, I've added code for the `GetCustomUI` method and snippets for the XML Markup I'm using to build the ribbon. It is strange that `Ribbon_OnLoad` doesn't fire for the inspector.

Comment: Note, you don't handle composed items. Only read-only inspectors are mentioned. Do you get any UI errors in Outlook?

Comment: In the production code I do handle Composed Items; however I have omitted them in the example above. I do not get any UI errors from Outlook. From what I've noticed it appears that the `onLoad` method defined in the XML markup will fire only once, for whichever object Outlook gets first whether Explorer or Inspector. Please correct me if I am wrong?